# MaxLine in Text Form Field

Tags: flutter, dart

I made an example with a text form field widget and set the max lines value to 2, but when the enter key is pressed, the text form field grows in size.I want when the enter key is pushed, the first line should disappear, the second line should add the same position , and the lines should be scrollable.

Code Snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            maxLines: 2,
           
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By copying your code to dartpad.dev it shows the behaviour you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain what you want just remove the `maxLines: 2,`

As montioned in the doc `{int? maxLines = 1}`

> The maximum number of lines to show at one time, wrapping if
> necessary. **This affects the height of the field itself and does not
> limit the number of lines** that can be entered into the field. If this
> is 1 (the default), the text will not wrap, but will scroll
> horizontally instead. If this is null, there is no limit to the number
> of lines, and the text container will start with enough vertical space
> for one line and automatically grow to accommodate additional lines as
> they are entered, up to the height of its constraints.

you can continue reading here [full documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText/maxLines.html)